# Use Fancybox jquery while having already onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, fancybox

I want on click of **ENLARGE** link to open my fancybox.

[image]

What I have till now is an ajax call so I can fill up my images based on a Project's id:

```
...
xmlhttp.open("GET", "desciptionImageHelper.aspx?id=" + id, true);
...
```

on my desciptionImageHelper.aspx I have a query where I get all the images of a project:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    litData.Text += "<a id='fancybox" + reader.GetInt32(0).ToString() + "' class='fancybox' rel='gallery1' onclick=\"javascript:imagePopup('" + reader.GetInt32(0).ToString() + "','" + reader.GetString(1) + "','" + reader.GetString(2) + "','" + reader.GetString(3) + "');\" ><img src=\"../helper/MediaImgHandler.ashx?imgid=" + reader.GetInt32(0).ToString() + "\"/></a>";
}
```

Which this `while` becomes:

```
<a id='fancybox4' class='fancybox' rel='gallery1' title='asdsad' onclick="javascript:imagePopup('4','Alululu Scetch','Photograph','Photoshop');" ><img src="../helper/MediaImgHandler.ashx?imgid=4"/></a>
<a id='fancybox13' class='fancybox' rel='gallery1' title='asdsad' onclick="javascript:imagePopup('13','Allalalala','Magazine article','PDF');" ><img src="../helper/MediaImgHandler.ashx?imgid=13"/></a>
<a id='fancybox22' class='fancybox' rel='gallery1' title='asdsad' onclick="javascript:imagePopup('22','PHOTOOO','Photograph','PDF');" ><img src="../helper/MediaImgHandler.ashx?imgid=22"/></a>
<a id='fancybox23' class='fancybox' rel='gallery1' title='asdsad' onclick="javascript:imagePopup('23','New Media','Journal article','Digital 3D Model');" ><img src="../helper/MediaImgHandler.ashx?imgid=23"/></a>
<a id='fancybox31' class='fancybox' rel='gallery1' title='asdsad' onclick="javascript:imagePopup('31','New media added on Aluminium','Film (cinema)','Digital Video');" ><img src="../helper/MediaImgHandler.ashx?imgid=31"/></a>
<a id='fancybox32' class='fancybox' rel='gallery1' title='asdsad' onclick="javascript:imagePopup('32','hahahaahha','Design development drawings','Digital Video');" ><img src="../helper/MediaImgHandler.ashx?imgid=32"/></a>
```

On left click on the image I get this box you see in the picture.

and the code is:

```
function imagePopup(id, title, media_type, format) {
        var popup = document.getElementById("imagePopup")
        popup.innerHTML = title + "<br /><span style='color:grey;margin-left:3px;'>" +
         media_type + " | " + format + "</span><br />" +
         "<a class='blueColor' onclick=\"javascript:getSummary(" + id + ",'m');" +
         "document.getElementById('projectNav').style.display = 'none';document.getElementById('left_right').style.display = 'none';displayMedia('" + title + "');$('#imagePopup').fadeOut('slow');\">SEE DETAILS</a><br />" +
         "<a id='enlarge' onclick=\"javascript:$('#fancybox" + id + "').attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox();\" class='blueColor' >ENLARGE</a>";

        $('#imagePopup').css({ 'top': mouseY, 'left': mouseX }).fadeIn('slow');

    }
```

But it is not working as a **gallery** and also when I view a picture(fancybox opens) the picture it is **disappeared** on my page.

I don't know what to do.
Is my code a mess? Should I follow another policy?

Comment: I took it from here: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally I came up with an idea of hiding the links with the .fancybox class and triggering it onclick of ENLARGE.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
       litData.Text += "<a onclick=\"javascript:imagePopup('" + reader.GetInt32(0).ToString() + "','" + reader.GetString(1) + "','" + reader.GetString(2) + "','" + reader.GetString(3) + "');\" ><img src=\"../helper/MediaImgHandler.ashx?imgid=" + reader.GetInt32(0).ToString() + "\"/></a>";
       litData.Text += "<a style='display:none' id='fancybox" + reader.GetInt32(0).ToString() + "' class='fancybox' rel='gallery1' title='asdsad' href=\"../helper/MediaImgHandler.ashx?imgid=" + reader.GetInt32(0).ToString() + "\" ></a>";
}
```

So on the one link I have an onclick event handler for the popup and for the other link I have my href="../.ashx".

```
 <a id='enlarge' onclick=\"javascript:$('#fancybox" + id + "').trigger('click');\" class='blueColor' >ENLARGE</a>
```

But the other problem I had to solve was that the image was showed via helper(.ashx).
I solved this by putting attribute `'type': 'image'` on fancybox!

Answer (score 0):

this line (inside your `imagePopup()` function) :

```
"<a id='enlarge' onclick=\"javascript:$('#fancybox" + id + "').attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox();\" class='blueColor' >ENLARGE</a>";
```

can be simply

```
"<a id='enlarge' rel='gallery' class='blueColor' >ENLARGE</a>";
```

(although I don't see the code you want it to be a gallery with, because you are trying to bind fancybox to the `ID` of an element so only one element would be allowed)

...then just add somewhere in your code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#enlarge").fancybox();
});
```

Comment: sure ... we are missing the `href` there... I saw that you just post your html. Why don't you build a `href` within the `while` loop and pass `id, title, media_type, format` as separated attributes rather than inside an `onclick` attribute? ... because even you can make it work like that you will never get a gallery. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I tried to use href, but on click it takes me to a separate page showing only the image!

Comment: do I have to use another way?